# Python: Detect camera shift angle comparing the reference image and live image taken from a camera

Tags: python, opencv, image-processing, computer-vision, correlation

For a project work, I need to find the camera shift angle using a reference image. I have fixed a CC camera and taken an image as a reference. On a regular interval, I need to check if anyone had changed the camera position. if yes, need to find the angle of camera shift. How can I achieve this?

[image: Sample image2]

[image: Sample image]

The images provided are just samples. Actually, the camera may be in an outdoor scenario. It may be fixed in a front gate or similar. Need to find if anybody has changed the camera position. Any camera tampering condition by shifting the camera position needs to be found. Can anyone help me to solve this? Any ideas?

`def find_angle(frame):
    frame = cv2.cvtColor(np.array(frame), cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
    referenceImage = cv2.imread(lux.camera_specs['data'][cameras]['reference_image'])
    referenceImage = cv2.resize(referenceImage, (480, 320))
    referenceImage = cv2.cvtColor(referenceImage, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
    referenceImage = np.float32(referenceImage)
    liveViewImage = np.float32(frame)
    shift = cv2.phaseCorrelate(referenceImage, liveViewImage)
    print (shift)
    fitGrade = shift[1]
    angle = math.sqrt((shift[0][0] * shift[0][0]) + (shift[0][1] * shift[0][1]))
    return fitGrade, angle`

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Comment: You can't without knowing your camera parameters. This problem is called camera calibration and has extensive literature.

Comment: I have tried using cv2.phaseCorrelate. But the results found so weird.

Comment: You need to have a set of key-points which are visible at each instant and detect their positions for each respective frame. This would be the starting point.

Comment: Actually, the camera may be in an outdoor scenario. It may be fixed in a front gate or similar. Need to find if anybody has changed the camera position.

Comment: Show us your code!

Comment: Try optical flow, based on which you can then estimate the scene shifts.

Comment: edited with the code sample. Can anyone tell me how to solve this?

Comment: @WDC can you please elaborate

Comment: [optical flow](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Optical_flow) tells you about how each pixel moves in neighboring frames. For your case there is a flow vector field that might help to determine the camera position change.

Comment: @WDC For optical flow determination, we can use phase correlation. right? If so, I have got the phase correlation values using the above code. How can I get the angle of change using it? Is my angle calculation formula right? Can you give any suggestions?

Comment: @KK I didn’t look into math details. But it seems your phase correlation is only just correlation (whose output is a 2D coordinate), while optical flow gives you global information that you can play with and estimate the scene.

Comment: @ZdaR Can you provide more details? Any library/functions for getting it would be more appreciatable.

Comment: Have tried optical flow too but the values don't match with the real cases. can anybody have suggestions for identifying the shift from live and a reference image?

Comment: what's up after 4 year ? I try to found some similar tools